# MongoDB complex MapReduce of video logs

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a dataset from video streaming logs. Each video is identified by a FileGUID. The log entries record the FileGUID, the fragment of the video watched and the bandwidth it was watched at.

I would like to create a mapreduce outputting, for each video, a count for fragments both total and for each bandwidth. Ideally it would look like;

```
{"FileGUID":"50acb3a5796634df0e073285",
  {
    "1":{"total":76, "0832":34, "1028":42},
    "2":{"total":42, "0832":28, "1028":14},
    ...
  }
}
```

Is this possible with one mapreduce or is it a multi-step process, or should I use a different method?

Here is a sample of the data.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("50acb3a5796634df0e073285"),
  "IP": "46.7.1.88",
  "DateTime": ISODate("2012-10-24T22:59:57.0Z"),
  "FileGUID": "8cdde821fb934a6da7c125a012a26612",
  "Bandwidth": NumberInt(1028),
  "Segment": NumberInt(1),
  "Fragment": NumberInt(237),
  "Status": NumberInt(200),
  "Size": NumberInt(576790),
  "UserAgent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/16.0"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("50acb3a5796634df0e073284"),
  "IP": "46.7.1.88",
  "DateTime": ISODate("2012-10-24T22:59:52.0Z"),
  "FileGUID": "8cdde821fb934a6da7c125a012a26612",
  "Bandwidth": NumberInt(1028),
  "Segment": NumberInt(1),
  "Fragment": NumberInt(236),
  "Status": NumberInt(200),
  "Size": NumberInt(577100),
  "UserAgent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/16.0"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("50acb3a5796634df0e073283"),
  "IP": "46.7.1.88",
  "DateTime": ISODate("2012-10-24T22:59:47.0Z"),
  "FileGUID": "8cdde821fb934a6da7c125a012a26612",
  "Bandwidth": NumberInt(0832),
  "Segment": NumberInt(1),
  "Fragment": NumberInt(234),
  "Status": NumberInt(200),
  "Size": NumberInt(576664),
  "UserAgent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/16.0"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("50acb3a5796634df0e073282"),
  "IP": "46.7.1.88",
  "DateTime": ISODate("2012-10-24T22:59:42.0Z"),
  "FileGUID": "8cdde821fb934a6da7c125a012a26612",
  "Bandwidth": NumberInt(0832),
  "Segment": NumberInt(1),
  "Fragment": NumberInt(233),
  "Status": NumberInt(200),
  "Size": NumberInt(575692),
  "UserAgent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/16.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single MapReduce job.

**The map function** emits the video IDs as a key and as value an object which consists of a single field. The field name is the bandwidth, the value is the running time of the current entry.

**The reduce function** sums up the objects fed to it. It iterates the values array, does a foreach loop over each array entry, and adds the value of each field to a field of the same name in the returned value.

**The finalize function** does a foreach loop over the resulting object and calculates the sum of all entries in it. It then puts the sum into the object as the field "total" (never do changes to an object you are currently looping over).